# Setting number format for a whole ASP (classic) application

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, localization

I have an old ASP classic app which were built to run on Internet Explorer 8. After IE is no longer supported, a problem raises. When opened on Edge or other popular browsers, all numeric text boxes and combo boxes display numbers using my country's format which is using comma for decimals. Unfortunately, the database uses period for decimals. This causes error in my app. How to set the decimal number format to English (US) for my web app which uses Indonesian format by default (preferably without using JavaScript)?

I have tried using `lang="en"` or `en-US` in `html`, `div`, and `input`. I also tried using `toLocaleString` method, even though I hope there is a solution without utilizing scripts.

**Update:**

I added the section below simply for showing that I have experimented with some solution candidates. However those candidates introduced new problems which is not ultimately the problem that I need to solve.

Later I created a simple code just to experiment with `lang` and `toLocaleString` and also to simulate the problem that I experience.

```html
<html lang="id">
<head lang="id">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log("document ready");
    
  $("#btn").click(function(){
    //console.log("btn.click");
    
    $("#inNum").attr("lang", "id");
    
    var lang = $("#inNum").attr("lang");
    
    //console.log("lang = " + lang);
    
    var inNumValue = parseFloat($("#inNum").val());
  
    //console.log("inNumValue = " + inNumValue);
    
    $("#inNum").val(ToLocale(inNumValue, "id")) 
  });
});

function ToLocale(num, locale){
    //console.log("ToLocale");
    //console.log("num = " + num);
    //console.log("locale = " + locale);
    
    return num.toLocaleString(locale);
}
</script>
</head>
<body lang="id">
<div lang="id">
  <input type="number" id="inNum" value="0.5" lang="id"/> 
  <input type="button" id="btn" value="button"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is what happened:

1. Since I can't test the code above on production, I tested it on my laptop. At first, I didn't use any `lang` attribute and the number format is automatically set to English. So "0.5" is a correct number.
2. Since I need to reproduce my problem and make my page to format decimal numbers using comma, I added `lang="id"` attributes. None of them has any effect to change the decimal number format to using comma.
3. Later I added a function to format numbers to Indonesian (id) format as follows

```
function ToLocale(num, locale){
    //console.log("ToLocale");
    //console.log("num = " + num);
    //console.log("locale = " + locale);
    
    return num.toLocaleString(locale);
}
```

This function worked and returned decimals using comma when I used `id` as the value for locale parameter. Thus if the value of `num` parameter is `0.5`, the output is `0,5`. Unfortunately, `0,5` cannot be accepted for the value of my HTML number input with error message `The specified value 'NaN' cannot be parsed, or is out of range.`. Perhaps I used `lang` attribute incorrectly?

However, please don't confuse my little experiment with the problem that I want to solve, which is to set the decimal format to English (US) in an ASP classic application which uses Indonesian number format by default.

Comment: Have you tried "id-ID" as your locale instead of "id"?

Comment: I have tried using "id-ID" on my small experiment code. I also have tried using "en-US" in my actual ASP app. None of them shows any effect.